# Are Git submodules a good idea to NOT force library users to download its tests?

Tags: git, testing, git-submodules

When developing a code library I would like to separate its tests from the actual code payload, as I believe when someone uses my library they just want to use it and they're not interested in testing it -- testing is my responsibility, not my users'.

I know that storage space is cheap and so is bandwidth, yet my principle is not to waste either of them.

I'm thinking of putting all the test code into a separate git repository, and use it as a git submodule in the main repository.

This way, those who're interested can still obtain and execute the tests, but normally when you clone the main repository, the only extra files are the empty directory for the submodule, and the .gitmodules file.

Is this a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have the actual library as one repository and the tests as another one, then include both as submodules in a super project that links the matching versions of both submodules. In that case, a user who needs just the library will require no knowledge of the existense of tests and they won't have to deal with submodules in any way.

Users who are familiar with submodules can clone the super project, if they are also interested in the tests, making the test payload optional.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, you can do this. But submodules are a tricky thing, and sometimes they are a bit complicated, so it takes time for some of your users who aren't familiar with them.

In my opinion, you can just package your tests with the library. Depending on your language, you can put them into an own package (Java), so you can exclude them in you build script (Ant/Make) when building release packages.

Storage is really cheap, and using submodules is a quite tricky thing. Also, it's quite an overcoming for some people (like me) to run tests, and it gets even harder when you have to see how submodules work. Also, remember: Good tests can also be used as documentation.